# Using a function as the lookup_value for MATCH

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to set up a formula for a two-way lookup that looks just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tSTc.png), except that I would like to use the RIGHT function as the argument for the lookup_value of MATCH.

Long story short, the formula only works if I use a plain number as the lookup_value (or reference a cell that contains a plain number, or a formula that simply returns a plain number). Using LEFT (or a reference to a cell that contains just the LEFT function) makes MATCH fail.

A double lookup with INDEX+MATCH also shows the same problem.

I have tried to simulate the issue in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJyBI.png). Can someone make sense of this behaviour, and hopefully point to any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the underlying issue is using RIGHT you receive a text answer, now numeric. The values you are looking up in your match are numbers. So in the screen cap below, you will see that if I add *1 to your formula you loose the n/a error.

[image]

Hopefully, this answers your questions.